# Json Schema validation: require at least one of two fields

Tags: javascript, json, validation, jsonschema

I am using the following Json Schema validation package:

https://github.com/hasbridge/php-json-schema

Using that validation package, I want to validate in the following scenario:

> **Fields** - `A`, `B`
>
> **Validation Condition** - If `A` value is sent then `B` is not required.
>   If `B` value is sent, then `A` is not required. But we need at least one of both field values in the form.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You want to know how to write a JSON Schema that requires at least A or B?

Comment: I cant see no code to help you debug.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - Yes you are right

Comment: May i know why down vote? Could you please explain that and raise down vote?

Answer (score 7):

This is a JSON Schema that tests for the presence of property `A` and/or `B`:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "A": {},
    "B": {}
  },
  "anyOf": [{
    "required" : ["A"]
  }, {
    "required" : ["B"]
  }]
}
```

Whether or not your PHP library supports this syntax is a different matter since the github page states that *[...] it is not yet feature complete*.

Here's a screenshot of testing it against [Newtonsoft's online JSON schema validator](http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/):

[image: Newtonsoft's online JSON schema validator]